# Why is my code of Linear search using "for-each loop" not working for mixed inputs?

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, linear-search

My code is working for ascending or descending array inputs like `11,12,13,14,15` etc....but it is not working for mixed order array inputs like `11 13 12 15 14`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LinearSearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int LS[]=new int[100];                      //LS is the array
        int n,key,flag=0;                          //n is the number of array elements and key is the element to be searched
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter no.of array elements");
        n=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter array elements");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        LS[i]=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter element to search");
        key=sc.nextInt();           
        for (int i:LS){
          if(LS[i]==key){
            flag=1;
            System.out.println(key+" is found at location "+(i+1));
          }
      }
      if(flag==0){
        System.out.println(key+" is not found");
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is here: `if(LS[i]==key)` you need to change as `if(i==key)` because ` for (int i:LS)` according to for loop i stands for elements of the array not the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here: `if(LS[i]==key)` you need to change as `if(i==key)` because according to for loop `for (int i:LS)` `i` stands for elements of the array not the index.

If you want to get the index of the element, you can use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i<LS.length; i++) {
    if(LS[i]==key){
        flag=1;
        System.out.println(key+" is found at location "+(i+1));
      }
}
```

One more thing:

You're asking for the number of elements, so it would be a better practice to initialize the array with `n` instead of `100` :

```
int LS[] = new int[n];
```

When you initialize the array, it allocates the memory according to the size. Think of `n` equals to `20`, then it would be a waste to initialize the array with size `100`

Otherwise if the user enters a value greater than 100, the program throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.